# Haskell type synonym declaration with constraint possible?

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism, constraints

Let's say I wanna make a type synonym for all lists with Int's.

I could do:

```
type NumberList = [Int]
```

But what if I want to call all lists that contains numbers NumberList? How would I put a constraint and say that all [a] as long as "Num a" should be called the same?

Edit:: After seeing the answers I rethought. It seemed like I was going against one of the basic ideas behind Haskell and the reward was relatively small (just a formal matter). I decided on this: If a type has the need for two instances identical to each other that only differ in Int or Float, then the difference between them is too small to warrant the workaround needed to accomplish the use of both Int and Float but calling them the same thing, which is why I must restrict the use to one of them. IF however there is an important reason to why I should have both, then I can probably reflect this important reason in the name of the instance and thereby avoid the problem by doing:

```
data Thing = Thing_A(String, String Float) | Thing_B(String,String,Int)
```

---and thereby stick to Haskell's typing system and still accept both of them as data type Thing. What I wanted to do at first was

```
data Thing = Thing(String, String, Float) | Thing(String, String, Int)
```

Comment: Do you want a value of type `NumberList` to be able to contain a list of any number, or to contain any list of numbers, or to be polymorphic and usable as a list of any numeric type?

Comment: A "`a` for some `Num a`" type would be quite useless because the Num typeclass doesn't allow you to get the numbers back out in any way. What do you want to do with such a list?

Comment: I'm gonna look into those answers... what I want to do? I want to create a data type where one of the value in the constructor is a [(Char, Int)] but in some cases one might have to use a [(Char,Float)] too and I want that both of them should be typed as my type named Profile (remember that there are other constructor values in there as well, not only the list with tuples)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Use data and parameters, not existentials to get contexts

I think if you wanted

```
data Thing = Good [(Char,Int)] | Bad String | Indifferent Leg
```

but also sometimes

```
data Thing = Good [(Char,Float)] | Bad String | Indifferent Arm
```

You could define

```
data Thing num bodypart = Good [(Char,num)] | Bad String | Indifferent bodypart
```

or if you want to make sure `num` is always numeric, you could do

```
data Num num => Thing num bodypart = Good [(Char,num)] | Bad String | Indifferent bodypart
```

and finally, you could restrict the types allowed in `bodypart` by defining your own class:

```
class Body a where
   -- some useful function(s) here

instance Body Leg where
   -- define useful function(s) on Legs
instance Body Arm
   -- define useful function(s) on Arms

data (Num num,Body bodypart) => Thing num bodypart = 
                                                             Good [(Char,num)] | Bad String | Indifferent bodypart
```

I'd like to discourage you from using existential types via the forall constructor or via GADTs because adding the `num` parameter to your data type is *considerably* more useful in practice, even though it takes more typing.

### Constraints on type synonyms?

Note that when you use a constraint like

```
data (Num num) => Thing num = T [(Char,num)]
```

really only changes the type of the constructor `T` to

```
T :: (Num num) => [(Char,num)] -> Thing num
```

instead of `T :: [(Char,num)] -> Thing num`. This means every time you use `T`, there needs to be a context `(Num num)`, but that's really what you wanted - to stop people putting data in your data type that isn't numeric.

A consequence of this fact is that you *can't* write

```
type Num num => [(Char,num)]
```

because there's no data constructor function `T` for the context `(Num num)` to be required on; if I have a [('4',False)], it automatically matches the type `[(Char,num)]` because it's a *synonym*. The compiler can't be going running around your code looking for instances before it decides what type something is. In the `data` case, it's got a constructor `T` that tells it the type, and it can guarantee there's a `Num num` instance because it checked your use of the function `T`. No `T`, no context.

Comment: Thanks for a thorough but still possible to understand explanation!

Comment: In your examples, you use `body` and `bodypart` to mean the same type, so this shouldn't compile. I could edit it, but editing to fix code is frowned on and I'd rather let you choose which name to use for the type variable.

Comment: @amalloy Thanks for that. I'd made another mistake with num, too. Are there any I haven't spotted?

Answer (score 10):

This corresponds to existential quantification. In pseudo-Haskell,

```
type NumberList = exists a . Num a => [a]
```

I say «pseudo» because GHC doesn't allow introducing existential quantifiers on the fly — you need to create a separate datatype for that.

Now, most of the type you'd use NumberList to the left of the arrow, where «exists» effectively changes its meaning to «forall».

That is, instead of writing

```
isIncreasing :: NumberList -> Bool
```

which is the same as

```
isIncreasing :: (exists a . Num a => [a]) -> Bool
```

you can write

```
isIncreasing :: forall a . Num a => [a] -> Bool
```

or simply

```
isIncreasing :: Num a => [a] -> Bool
```

Of course, having a type synonym seems like less code, but it has disadvantages as well.
These disadvantages, by the way, are typical for object-oriented programming, which is based on the existential approach.

For example, you want to concatenate two lists. Ordinarily you would write

```
(++) :: forall a . [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

(where again `forall` is unnecessary and added for clarity). Since `a` is the same across the entire signature, that ensures that you are concatenating lists of the same type.

How do we concatenate two numeric lists? A signature

```
(++) :: NumberList -> NumberList -> NumberList
```

wouldn't work, since one list may contain Ints and the other may contain Doubles. And the resulting NumberList has to contain values of a single type.

Or, say, you want to find the sum of the list elements.

Usually you write

```
sum :: Num a => [a] -> a
```

Notice that the result type is the same as the type of list elements. Alas, we cannot do the same for NumberList!

```
sum :: NumberList -> ???
```

What is the result type? We could apply existential quantification there as well.

```
sum :: NumberList -> (exists a . Num a => a)
```

But now the connection between the original list type and the sum type is lost — at least for Haskell's type system. If you then decide to write a function like

```
multiplySum :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Integer
multiplySum x ys = x * sum ys
```

then you'll get a type error, because `sum ys` may be of any type, not necessarily of type Integer.

It would work if you pushed everything to extreme and made every type existentially-quantified — but then you'd end up essentially with another object-oriented-like language with all their problems.

(That said, there are some good use cases for existential quantification, of course.)

Comment: Thanks for an effective demonstration of why I should rethink which I did... thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

GHC allows this using RankNTypes.

So you can do this:

```
type NumList = forall a . (Num a ,Fractional a) => [a]
```

And then if we have:

```
numList:: NumList
numList = [1,2,3]

fracList:: NumList
fracList = [1.3,1.7]
```

doing a concatenation yields :

```
fracList ++ numList :: Fractional a => [a]
```

which NumList is a synonym of.
All in all i really don't see the point in this case.

Comment: Seems like an interesting area, this RankNTypes.. might look into it later but I decided after going through your answers that I was going against Haskell doing this which made me rethink... Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It makes not much sense to have such a type when you can't recover that original type. If you need just certain `Num`s, you should simply wrap them instead of conjuring heavy magick:

```
data NumWrapper = WInt Int 
                | WDouble Double 
                | WFloat Float 
                deriving Show

numList :: [NumWrapper]
numList = [WInt 12, WFloat 1.2, WDouble 3.14]
```

If you *really* want to be open for arbitrary `Num` types, then a list might be just the wrong collection for you. There are HLists etc, see http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Heterogenous_collections

Comment: Thanks! I understand this suggestion... It would work for me but give me a lot of headache too so you sort of pointed me in the direction that I went, namely that what I was trying wasn't so good taste.. thanks!